# Async replication of Topic partitions in a Confluent Server Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

The use of Observers is described in the below article link but it seems it's not working for me.

I've gone through this [article](https://docs.confluent.io/current/multi-dc-deployments/multi-region.html#observers) by Confluent.

Configuration to achieve -

- Multi DC Kafka Setup
- Leader and a follower in the same DC
- A follower and an Observer in another DC

Or are there any other ways through which I can achieve async replication of the partitions.

```
JSON Content:
{
    "version": 1,
    "observers": [
        {
            "count": 1,
            "constraints": {
                "rack": "rack2"
            }
    }
    ]
}
```

> Environment Description:
> ZK
> |- Broker1 (Rack1)
> |- Broker2 (Rack1)
> |- Broker3 (Rack2)

```
Command used to create topic: 
./bin/kafka-topics.sh  --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testing-observers --partitions 3  --replica-placement /home/nihal/kafka/testing-observers.json  

Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: replica-placement is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:650)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:51)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Thanks.

Comment: "seems it's not working for me"... Please describe in more detail your problem

Comment: @OneCricketeer The commands mentioned in the above URL throws error. Also when we execute the command line script to create a topic with observer, it doesn't work.

Comment: What error? Doesn't work how? Please edit your question to show your properties and commands you've ran. Also what version of confluent platform?

Answer (score 0):

Natively, stretch clusters are a bad idea across datacenters.

You can use MirrorMaker, Replicator, etc to replicate whole topics, but I typically find that partition replication is usually good enough across cloud availability zones, for example

Comment: I'm looking to implement this as an active-active cluster. Replication might not help me to achieve this.

Comment: I currently use replication for active-active. The confluent blogs on Replicator show how it's possible, or you can use MirrorMaker2, which was built for that use-case